# One column in a Pandas data frame with a varying number of values

Tags: python, pandas

Let’s say that I have the following Pandas data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ids = np.arange(1, 21)

children_count = np.random.randint(1, 16, size=len(ids)).astype(float)
children_count[np.random.choice(len(ids), size=10, replace=False)] = np.nan  # Adding some NaN values

def generate_age_string(count):
    if np.isnan(count):
        return np.nan
    else:
        ages = [str(np.random.randint(0, 19)) + " years" for _ in range(int(count))]
        return " and ".join(ages)

age = [generate_age_string(count) for count in children_count]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ids,
    'children_count': children_count,
    'age': age
})

print(df)
```

What approach should I take in order to tidy the data in the `age` column? I don't have any particular expected output. The only thing that I have in mind is to create an additional column for every age, but that might add too many columns. Is there another viable option?

Comment: Please don't use images of data. Provide a [mre]. What is the output of `df.head().to_dict('list')`? (please [edit] your question with this output)

Comment: Also provide your ideal expected output.

Comment: The question lacks clarity, as pointed out by @mozway, and is seeking recommendations, both of which are reasons to close a question. Review [ask].

Answer (score 2):

If you want a tidy format (i.e. a long format), then [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
out = (df.drop(columns='age')
         .join(df['age'].str.extractall(r'(?P<age>\d+)\syears')
                        .droplevel('match'))
      )
```

Output:

```
    id  children_count  age
0    1             NaN  NaN
1    2             NaN  NaN
2    3             NaN  NaN
3    4             7.0    6
3    4             7.0    4
..  ..             ...  ...
19  20            13.0    9
19  20            13.0   14
19  20            13.0    5
19  20            13.0    9
19  20            13.0    3

[79 rows x 3 columns]
```

Alternatively, for a wide format (this wastes more space if many different number of children), [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) before joining:

```
out = (df.drop(columns='age')
         .join(df['age'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)\syears')[0]
                        .unstack('match').add_prefix('Child'))
      )
```

Output:

```
    id  children_count Child0 Child1 Child2 Child3 Child4 Child5 Child6 Child7 Child8 Child9 Child10 Child11 Child12
0    1             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1    2             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2    3             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3    4             7.0      6      4     10     16      6     13     14    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4    5            11.0      7      9     12     16     16      4      6     12     16      7       1     NaN     NaN
5    6             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
6    7            13.0     17     17     18     11      1     17      1      3     16      9       7      11       0
7    8             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
8    9             9.0     12      7      8     17      9      1     13     13     11    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
9   10             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
10  11             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
11  12             2.0     12     14    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
12  13             6.0     11     12      4      6      8      3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
13  14             3.0     18     12     12    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
14  15             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
15  16             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
16  17             1.0     11    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
17  18             4.0     13     13      8      0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
18  19             NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
19  20            13.0     18     18      4      1     13     14      7      7      9     14       5       9       3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate rows for each item in the list by using Pandas [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're expecting to use this data.

You can extract the ages and add them into lists with `Series.str.findall`:

```
df["age"] = df["age"].dropna().str.findall(r"\b\d+\b")
```

```
    id  children_count                                                age
0    1             NaN                                                NaN
1    2             NaN                                                NaN
2    3            14.0      [0, 5, 5, 4, 11, 14, 3, 4, 8, 14, 3, 9, 0, 0]
3    4             9.0                    [12, 1, 14, 14, 12, 8, 1, 7, 5]
...
```

After that you can also split each age into a row with `df.explode`. This will duplicate the data contained in columns `id` and `children_count`, but again it could be appropriate or not depending on how you're expecting to use it.

```
df = df.explode(column="age")
```

```
    id  children_count  age
0    1             1.0    0
1    2             NaN  NaN
2    3            11.0    9
2    3            11.0   12
2    3            11.0   18
..  ..             ...  ...
18  19            11.0   12
18  19            11.0   16
18  19            11.0    9
18  19            11.0    4
19  20             NaN  NaN
```

Finally, unless you have a specific need for this, IMHO creating new columns for each age wouldn't make much sense.